# How to label barcharts in Plots.jl?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I can do a simple barplot

```
using Plots
bar([1,2,3])
```

but how do I label the bars as "a", "b", "c"?

Comment: Good question. In the worst-case scenario, we can use `annotate!` to manually put the labels on the bars. Looking forward to learn the correct way of doing it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put labels on the x axis you can do the following:

```
bar(["a","b","c"],[1,2,3])
```

If you wanted to put the labels anywhere else then it does seem like `annotate!` would be your best option, as juliohm suggested.